# Keep pressing key or something wired happen in my HP Laptop

Tags: hp-laptop

From month ago I was experiencing some wired behavior in my HP laptop.
Laptop - HP PROBOOK 450 GS , Intel core i7 8th Gen

It seems some key pressed. I identified it when I'm running CMD or SSH client.

[image]

[image]

When it happens I can't even type properly. When I'm browser it blinks in address bar.
And laptop doesn't identify my instructions(clicks or key instructions) until I press key in keyboard.

Any idea or solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the keyboard is failing you should replace it

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound